# How to determine String file location path in Java

Tags: java

Trying to use

```
System.getProperty("user.home/myfile.txt")
```

getting `NullPointerException`

Using String path

```
 String("/Users/user/myfile.txt")
```

everything works well.

Need universal way of files location.
Not everyone have the same path :)

I'm on MacOSX 10.11. java 8

Thanks

Comment: First of all, debugging questions do not belong on Programmers.SE, they should go on StackOverflow. Secondly, the reason you're getting an error is because there is no "user.home/mytextfile.txt" property defined in the System. You will need to combine the "user.home" property with your filename string to get the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.getProperty("user.home/myfile.txt")
```

There is no system property called `user.home/myfile.txt` what you probably mean is

```
System.getProperty("user.home") + "/myfile.txt";
```